# Updating multiple classes with random background colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

At the moment I have a website at http://projects.jack-spence.com/mortune/index.html . However I would like to change the background colors on the cards (When they're flipped) to a random color.

I'm currently using

```
    <script>
function get_random_color() {
var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
var color = '#';
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
    color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
}
return color;
}

$(function() {
$(".face,.back").each(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", get_random_color());
});
});
</script>
```

At the moment. But it won't update multiple classes as I need it to update ".face.back " and it just doesn't seem to work... I don't know if I've given enough detail. But any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your random generator is biased. Use `return  "#"+("00000"+Math.floor(Math.random()*(1<<24)).toString(16)).slice(-6).toUpperCase()`

Comment: Typo? There's a comma in `$(".face,.back")`.

Comment: @Armin That really has no difference

Comment: What do you mean 'it just doesnt seem to work' ? are you saying the color generator isnt working or the selector isnt working?

Comment: Your generator works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/dCKT2/

Comment: Either OP made a typo, or isn't showing real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the script. It is the fact, that $ is unknown at the moment you call it. Just look to console on your website:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Because the path to jquery.js is broken (jquery is not existing at this path).

Comment: Often the little things in life are those making a difference :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I put together. Works like a charm for me.

```
var rgb = [];

for (var i = 0;i < 3; i++) rgb[i] = Math.floor((Math.random()*255)+1);

$('.face').css('background-color','rgb('+rgb[0]+','+rgb[1]+','+rgb[2]+')');
```

Comment: What is that `+1` doing there?

Comment: Gives you a number between 1 and 255, rather than 0-254.

Comment: Yes. But why would `0` be an invalid color value?

Comment: It's not. Haha. I wrote that piece a long time ago before I took the time to understand it and never changed it. You caught me!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
$(".face,.back").each(function() {
$(this).css("background-color", get_random_color());
});
});
```

is overly complicated

Why not just use:

```
$(".face,.back").css("background-color", get_random_color());
```

This will also have to be wrapped in a callable function if you want to do this when the user tries to do something instead of every time the page is loaded.

Comment: That gives them all the same background color, which is probably not intended. But you could pass a callback function to `.css` (http://jsfiddle.net/dCKT2/1/)